# Proving a quantity negative.

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, inequality

For $j\in{1,2,3}$ let $x_j,y_j \in R$ be nonzero and let $v_j=x_j+y_j$. Suppose that following holds:
$$x_1x_2x_3=−y_1y_2y_3 \quad \text{and} \quad x^2_1+x^2_2+x^2_3=y^2_1+y^2_2+y^2_3$$
nd that whenever $\{i,j,k\}=\{1,2,3\}$ we have $v_i+v_j>v_k$ and $v^2_i+v^2_j>v^2_k$.

Prove that then exactly one of $x_1, x_2, x_3, y_1, y_2$ and $y_3$ is negative.